# How to check duplicate username in the database?

Tags: php, insert, save

I have a problem to save the data into the database. My case is when I save the data into the database table (`user`), the new username must cannot same with exist username in the table.

Below is my code to check whether insert username is the same for the existing username if not the same then can insert to the table, but my code doesn't work, anyone can guide me which part I get wrong.

`save`

```
$arr_val = $_POST;
$arr_val = $_POST;

$loc = $arr_val['loc'];
$action = $arr_val['action'];
$id = $arr_val['id'];
$type = $arr_val['type'];

unset($arr_val['loc']);
unset($arr_val['action']);
unset($arr_val['filter_id']);
unset($arr_val['type']);
$table = 'user';
if ($action == 'save') {

$query_user = mysqli_query($mysql_con, 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username="' . $arr_val['username'] . '"');
$num_user = mysqli_num_rows($query_user);


if(count($num_user)>0){
                        echo "Duplicate username";
                    }elseif($num_user == 0) {
$key_relationship_1[] = 'is_active';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value('1');
$key_relationship_1[] = 'user_type';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value('1');
$key_relationship_1[] = 'created';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value($cur_dt);
$key_relationship_1[] = 'createdby';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value($user_name);
$key_relationship_1[] = 'modified';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value($cur_dt);
$key_relationship_1[] = 'modifiedby';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value($user_name);
$key_relationship_1[] = 'username';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value($_POST['username']);
$key_relationship_1[] = 'name';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value($_POST['name']);
$key_relationship_1[] = 'email';
$val_relationship_1[] = convert_db_value($_POST['email']);

$row_insert = db_conn_insert('user', $key_relationship_1, $val_relationship_1);
$sql_insert = $row_insert['sql'];
$error_insert = $row_insert['error'];
$record_id = $row_insert['record_id'];


unset($key_relationship_1);
unset($val_relationship_1);
                    }
elseif ($row_insert) {
    echo 'Saved successfully';

}
```

The output shows me like the below:

[image: Output of save]

This output I try to insert the same username with the table "user".

If remove the "count", the output show like below:

[image]

Comment: What is `$query_setting_company`?

Comment: @HasithaJayawardana edited already. It is $num_user

Comment: remove your `count` and use `$num_user > 0` only

Comment: @HasithaJayawardana I have tried to remove `count`, you can see in my question there.

Comment: What is the PHP error you got? Did you use `if($num_user > 0)`?

Comment: I use if($num_user > 0)

Comment: Where you get `loading fail` error? Don't you have a PHP error log?

Comment: add unique constrain to username column

Comment: In my js file to get loading error

Comment: Post whole code. So we can check.

Comment: @HasithaJayawardana My code too long. Can you teamviewer help me?

Comment: I will not be able right now. But you can show us the code. No need for the whole code but the full code that belongs to this process. And you can use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to show us the code.

Comment: is this your full code @O.Soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never rely solely on the result of SELECT to determine if a record is unique. It's possible for another process to INSERT a record with the same value between the time when your SELECT completes and when your subsequent INSERT completes -- and then you've got duplicates. The *only* way you should be ensuring unique values in a database field is by using a `UNIQUE` constraint on it. Implementations vary, but [**here**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) is an example in MySQL.

With a `UNIQUE` constrait in place, a duplicate INSERT attempt will fail, so you'll need to ensure that you're checking the return status of all your database function calls.

Also note that your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a number of users from the following query,

```
$num_user = mysqli_num_rows($query_user);
```

[mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) will always return the number of rows in the result set.

But in the following statement,

```
if(count($num_user) > 0) {
   echo "Duplicate username";
}
```

you are using [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function. The `count()` function returns the number of elements in an array. Since `$num_user` isn't an array you should get an error as follows,

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable

You don't need to use `count()` function because `$num_user` is already a number.

Just use as follows,

```
if($num_user > 0) {
   echo "Duplicate username";
}
```

Hope this helps you!